# Windows Phone tiles in app

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app, and have a question about UI design. Please take a look at the image below:

[image: Windows Phone 8 App Sample Image]

What I am trying to add to my app is something like the above UI under "recent" tab. That is, some kind of live tile style thing with-in the app.

If anyone has experience about how to build such kind of in-app tiles, please share some idea or code sample.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) provides a Windows Phone HubTile control:

[image: HubTile control]

[Here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HubTile_in_Windows_Phone) is a tutorial on the Nokia Wiki that explains how to use it.

Comment: 2 years later it's still not ported to Windows Phone 8.1...and then Microsoft wonders why nobody develops for their platform...

Answer (score 2):

Use `HubTile` control from [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) library.

There are couple tutorials about that control available, e.g.

- http://igrali.com/2011/08/19/how-to-use-the-hubtile-control/,
- http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HubTile_in_Windows_Phone